# Add Lock to iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm creating an app that will let you browse your emails and compose emails. This is dangerous since you won't need to be logging in each time. I was wondering how I could create a ViewController that asks the user for a password of their choice and if it's correct, will allow them to continue to the email, other wise, display a message saying that it is an incorrect password. I would also like to include Touch ID but I already have that covered.

Comment: What's your question? It's unclear what help you need here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UIView that contains a UITextField and a UIButton. The user can type in a password and hit the button and if the password string is equal to a string stored in NSUserDefaults then it will allow the user to get through, otherwise you can show a UIAlertView saying the password is incorrect.

Example:

```
//PASSWORD_KEY is equal to the password

if ([self.textField.text isEqualToString:PASSWORD_KEY]){
// allow access
} else {
// show alert
}
```

Comment: As an added bonus, store the string to NSUserDefaults as a hash, then when the user enters a string into your text field, compare the hash values. This way you're never storing the password just in case it's super secret and people care.

Comment: @IanMacDonald, yes that is a good idea. This is more of a general idea of how to this. I wasn't going to write the whole program for him, haha!

Comment: Storing the password in the device keychain would also work. Never store a password in plain-text.

Comment: @rebello95 that is also true. The question though was more addressing how to check to see if a password matched text input by the user - not storing the password itself.

Comment: @WyattMufson Agreed, just figured I'd mention it for completeness :)